# joomla: ja-university where to locate header layout

Tags: joomla

I want to add a module position inside header in Joomla ja-university template. I tried to find header template to add a new module position. But, I could not locate the header template. How can I add a module position inside header.

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation for the T3 framework?

Comment: Yes, I had a look at a some documents. I had noticed that there is "header.php" file in layout folder for some templates. But, I could not find any layout for header for ja-university template.